# How long does it take for the approval of an Microsoft Edge extension?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

We submitted a Microsoft Edge extension over three weeks ago to the request form: https://aka.ms/extension-request.
We did not receive any feedback yet and when submitting the extension package in the developer dashboard, we receive the following error

> Package acceptance validation error: com.microsoft.edge.extension is a reserved extension type. Your app does not have permission to use this extension type. To request permission, please use our extension submission form: https://aka.ms/extension-request

Does anybody have experience how long it takes to have your Edge extension approved?

(When trying to address this to support, they redirect us to a paid Edge support.)

Comment: Nice, this gave me the "tumbleweed" badge (Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week).

Comment: Have you got approval for your extension?How much time it took to get approval?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Any updates on whether they are making progress?  I have an extension that I submitted over a year ago and haven't heard anything from them.  I ported it from Chrome.

Comment: Edge Chromium now has a new extension submission process. But our extension "hanged" without approval, exactly like it was with old Edge extensions. Are there any Edge Chromium extensions that were approved by Microsoft? What is the typical approval time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft does not currently approve any new extensions. [There are only 77 extensions for today](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/store/collections/edgeextensions/pc).

Here is an article about this issue: https://www.computerworld.com/article/3230447/web-browsers/microsoft-defends-sluggish-ramp-up-of-extensions-for-edge-browser.html